# load image in picturebox quickly

Tags: vb.net, image, picturebox, performance

I have a program that shows previews of jpgs in small pictureboxes. The loading of these images is slow, and takes almost a second for each. That is because the images are big (8/9 mB). I would need to load them quickly, for example by loading a thumb of the picture. I would like to avoid putting all into the memory since there could be hundreds of pictures.

what is your advice on this?

THanks

Comment: It's probably slow because each image is being resized by the picture box and resizing is a CPU-intensive operation. Properly sized thumbnails would no doubt fix the problem. Are you getting your images over a network? If so, have your server generate the thumbnails.

Comment: nope, its on the local drive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resize the pictures in advance.

Creating tumbnails would be equally slow because you need to read the whole file, before you can even start making the tumbnail.

What you could do is, just like windows, create a tumbnail 'data base', where you store the tumbs for each picture. And only use the full size picture if needed.

So if you have like,

```
picture001.jpg
picture002.jpg
picture003.jpg
```

Create tumbs for each one;

```
picture001.jpg
picture001_tumb.jpg
picture002.jpg
picture002_tumb.jpg
picture003.jpg
picture003_tumb.jpg
```

So in the loading of the picuters detect, if the _tumb.jpg is there, if not create and store it. Which ofcourse, needs to be done in a background worker, because you need your main app to responsive...

You can also use this code, to request the icon from the windows shell;

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text

' http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?617626-How-do-I-extract-a-256X256-image-out-of-an-icon&highlight=IShellItemImageFactory

Module GetShellIcon
    <Flags()> _
    Public Enum SIIGBF
        SIIGBF_RESIZETOFIT = 0
        SIIGBF_BIGGERSIZEOK = 1
        SIIGBF_MEMORYONLY = 2
        SIIGBF_ICONONLY = 4
        SIIGBF_THUMBNAILONLY = 8
        SIIGBF_INCACHEONLY = 16
    End Enum

    Public Enum SIGDN As UInteger
        NORMALDISPLAY = 0
        PARENTRELATIVEPARSING = &H80018001UI
        PARENTRELATIVEFORADDRESSBAR = &H8001C001UI
        DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING = &H80028000UI
        PARENTRELATIVEEDITING = &H80031001UI
        DESKTOPABSOLUTEEDITING = &H8004C000UI
        FILESYSPATH = &H80058000UI
        URL = &H80068000UI
    End Enum

    <ComImportAttribute(), GuidAttribute("bcc18b79-ba16-442f-80c4-8a59c30c463b"),     InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
    Public Interface IShellItemImageFactory
        Sub GetImage(ByVal size As SIZE, ByVal flags As SIIGBF, ByRef phbm As IntPtr)
    End Interface

    <ComImport()> <Guid("43826d1e-e718-42ee-bc55-a1e261c37bfe")>     <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
    Public Interface IShellItem
        Sub BindToHandler(ByVal pbc As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)>     ByVal bhid As Guid, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal riid As Guid, ByRef ppv As     IntPtr)
        Sub GetParent(ByRef ppsi As IShellItem)
        Sub GetDisplayName(ByVal sigdnName As SIGDN, ByRef ppszName As IntPtr)
        Sub GetAttributes(ByVal sfgaoMask As UInt32, ByRef psfgaoAttribs As UInt32)
        Sub Compare(ByVal psi As IShellItem, ByVal hint As UInt32, ByRef piOrder As     Integer)
    End Interface

    <DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig:=False)> _
    Public Sub SHCreateItemFromParsingName(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal     pszPath As String, ByVal pbc As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal riid As     Guid, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface, IidParameterIndex:=2)> ByRef ppv As IShellItem)
    End Sub

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure SIZE
        Public cx As Integer
        Public cy As Integer
        Public Sub New(ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer)
            Me.cx = cx
            Me.cy = cy
        End Sub
    End Structure

    Public Function GetShellIcon(ByVal Path As String, MySIIGBF As SIIGBF, Optional ByVal Width As Integer = 256, Optional ByVal Height As Integer = 256) As Bitmap

        Dim ppsi As IShellItem = Nothing
        Dim hbitmap As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim uuid As New Guid("43826d1e-e718-42ee-bc55-a1e261c37bfe")

        Dim bs As Bitmap

        SHCreateItemFromParsingName(Path, IntPtr.Zero, uuid, ppsi)
        DirectCast(ppsi, IShellItemImageFactory).GetImage(New SIZE(Width, Height), MySIIGBF, hbitmap)
        bs = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hbitmap)
        bs.MakeTransparent(Color.Black)

        Return bs

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: makes sense.. is there even a solution to this?

Comment: thanks, is there a Windows-comand to do that automatically? or to read them out? by using Windows standard i mean.. the users would kill me if i make the drive full of thumbnails..

Comment: Best thing to do, ofcourse, hook to a existing system. I know windows creates a tumb_db file which contains the tumbs for each image in that folder. You could try to figure out a way to read the tumb database of windows... You won't have to reinvent the wheel that way :)

Comment: is the Windows tumbs system accessible?